# Xpath OR condition for two different elements in the DOM

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, jbehave

I have a selenium jbehave project with maven build.in step class i want to add an OR condition for two types of DOM elements.for same element i know how to do it.how can i do it for different elements?

```
@Then("I click $Search Button")
public void clickSearchGoogleButton(String search) {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@aria-label='"+search+"']")).click();
}
```

in the above code what i want to do is i have a button element with "aria-label"
so i want to add it to the same xpath condition with an or condition.i have tried below but it gives an error.

```
@Then("I click $Search Button")
public void clickSearchGoogleButton(String search) {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@aria-label='"+search+"'] or //button[@aria-label='"+search+"']")).click();
}
```

any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `|` instead of `or`

```
By.xpath("//input[@aria-label='"+search+"'] | //button[@aria-label='"+search+"']")
```

Comment: Thank you very much...!! this sorted that out.

Comment: You could also stick with your original xpath, but replace the input tag with an asterisk (*) unless there are potentially other elements with the same aria-label value.